# Login happens multiple times in order to get logged through Azure AD

Tags: python, azure, authentication, flask, azure-active-directory

So I am building a web app and the application refuses to login on the first attemt using the MS Azure system. This works perfectly when the web app is hosted locally but when I deploy the web app the website becomes glitchy.

```
@app.route("/login")
def login():
    return render_template("login.html", version=identity.__version__, **auth.log_in(
        scopes=SCOPE, # Have user consent to scopes during log-in
        redirect_uri=url_for("auth_response", _external=True), # Optional. If present, this absolute URL must match your app's redirect_uri registered in Azure Portal
        ))
#Provided by azure
@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    return redirect(auth.log_out(url_for("home", _external=True)))

@app.route(REDIRECT_PATH)
def auth_response():
    result = auth.complete_log_in(request.args)
    if "error" in result:
        return render_template("auth_error.html", result=result)
    return redirect(url_for("home"))
```

```
--init file--

import os
import urllib.parse 
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_session import Session

import B2CDash.app_config 

app = Flask(__name__,template_folder='templates')
app.config.from_object(B2CDash.app_config)


SECRET_KEY = 'some key'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % B2CDash.app_config.DB
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY
Session(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
from B2CDash.models import DashAccess
```

```
import os

b2c_tenant = os.getenv('TENANT_NAME')
signupsignin_user_flow = os.getenv('SIGNUPSIGNIN_USER_FLOW')
editprofile_user_flow = os.getenv('EDITPROFILE_USER_FLOW')

#db Connection string
user_id = os.getenv('DB_USERID')
password = os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')

resetpassword_user_flow = os.getenv('RESETPASSWORD_USER_FLOW')  # Note: Legacy setting.

authority_template = "https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{user_flow}"
db_template = "DRIVER={SQLServer};SERVER=tcp:mydb.database.windows.net,1433;DATABASE=csoc-dashboard;UID={user_id};PWD={password};Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no"


# Application (client) ID of app registration
CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("CLIENT_ID")
# Application's generated client secret: never check this into source control!
CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")

AUTHORITY = authority_template.format(tenant=b2c_tenant, user_flow=signupsignin_user_flow)
B2C_PROFILE_AUTHORITY = authority_template.format(tenant=b2c_tenant, user_flow=editprofile_user_flow)
DB = db_template.format(user_id = user_id, password = password,SQLServer= "{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}")
B2C_RESET_PASSWORD_AUTHORITY = authority_template.format(tenant=b2c_tenant, user_flow=resetpassword_user_flow)
# If you are using the new
# "Recommended user flow" (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-versions),
# you can remove the resetpassword_user_flow and the B2C_RESET_PASSWORD_AUTHORITY settings from this file.

REDIRECT_PATH = "/getAToken"  # Used for forming an absolute URL to your redirect URI.
# The absolute URL must match the redirect URI you set
# in the app's registration in the Azure portal.

# This is the API resource endpoint (*not* the endpoint of this app!)
ENDPOINT = ''

# These are the scopes you've exposed in the web API app registration in the Azure portal
SCOPE = []

SESSION_TYPE = "filesystem"  # Specifies the token cache should be stored in server-side session
```

I tried a few things to try and rectify. First I re-created the entire web app to make sure it has nothing to do with the way it is set up. I also increased the pricing tier in order to get better CPU. I also tried to create custom redirects to see if that would be the issue but my knowledge is pretty limited when it comes to that.

Comment: Can you share specific details for what you mean by "becomes glitchy"? Can you also share specific details for how your app is deployed? (E.g. enough for me to try to do the same thing)

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret We create an app service to host the web application. The glitchiness is from trying to log in. It redirects back to the login page multiple times (each time you attempt to log in) after multiple attempt it finally logs you into the website.

Comment: That's not enough detail for me to try to reproduce the problem. Can you describe the minimal steps to reproduce the problem end-to-end (including the code to deploy, and how you're configuring the Azure App Service instance)?

Comment: Sorry about that I am a fairly new developer so I didn't understand fully the scope of the question. I deployed everything through the Azure website. I created a new app service using Python 3.11. Then I linked it to my git hub using CI. I also created the Azure ad b2c and registered the app to have a redirect there. (above I also included more of the setup code)  Once all that was done GitHub auto built and deployed the web application.

Answer (score 0):

> This works perfectly when the web app is hosted locally but when I deploy the web app the website becomes glitchy.

In B2C app registrations make sure that the app has a redirect to the new url along with the local addresses.